# Disable back space key for browser based AS3 application

Tags: actionscript-3, browser, backspace

this is insanely annoying problem:

AS3 full screen application based on ADOBE FLEX 4, text field. User types something in text field, and then starts clicking backspace many many times to remove what he just wrote, and for some reason, instead of removing characters from text field it tells browser to GO BACK and user navigates away. Why?! Please, please help, this is so terrible. My users are losing important unsaved this is data while using my application!

i am using safari browser
PLEASE HELP.

Wow, this is terrible, I am so irritated, it happens every single time

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the focus is lost from your text field when hitting the `backspace` multiple times (check if you are firing some events on the text field that may cause this), which causes the main window to take focus and trigger 'Back' on the browser.

Comment: The focus is not lost. It happens even when you hit backspace once.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that the browser carries out keyboard shortcuts REGARDLESS of the flash app having the focus or not. From what I heard this problem does not exist on Safari's for Mac, only Safari for Windows.

I would check to see what browser you are in and then create a popup saying you this app does NOT work on Safari browser ON windows.

Scratching head*
Well maybe if HAD to solve this, I would use the ExternalInterface to interact with Safari or javascript to PREVENT the history back button from getting applied. So it won't go back to an old page. That is what I would look into.

Comment: But is there a workaround for that in Safari on Windows? Disabling Safari on Windows support is absolutely not an option, the application has to work universally.

Comment: This is out of your hands. This is a bug in Safari 5.1. If you use Safari 5.05 it works fine. So far no fix was posted. There were workarounds.

Comment: Here is a link to apples support forums discussing this topic ... https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2703807?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Is it possible to just completely disable backspace/browser back functionality for my web page? My users won't mind.

Comment: I think the users can configure it. Dont think you can configure it via flash, maybe through some hooks to Safari? See: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html